# Comparing cells with array and printing rows acording to comparison

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm quite newbie to python and pandas... so I'm using pandas to read and work with .CSV and others excel files... and now I have excel file that looks lets say like this:

```
  A B C D E
f - - - - 1
g - - - - 2
h - - - - 4
i - - - - 8
j - - - - 9
```

And I have array x[2,4,9,11,20] (in my case the array and the excel file is much bigger but I want to keep it simple for now) and I would like to compare column E to that array and print rows where E equals any value from x... so the output would looked like:

```
  A B C D E
g - - - - 2
h - - - - 4
j - - - - 9
```

Any idea how can I do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

using`.isin`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,20,30,40,50],
                   'E':[1,2,4,8,9]})

x = [2,4,9,11,20]

df1 = df.iloc[df[df.isin(x)].dropna(how='all').index]

print (df1)

        A   E
   1    20  2
   2    30  4
   4    50  9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boolean indexing with [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
x = [2, 4, 9, 11, 20]

df = df[df['E'].isin(x)]
```

Alternatively, you can [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) your dataframe:

```
df = df.query('E in @x')
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try a simple conditional, not sure if this will work I don't have any code running.

```
df[df["E"] in our_array]
```

does that not work?